# Unreal engine и Kotlin код

Tags: android, kotlin, unreal-engine-5

Я хочу начать писать игру на UE5 и тут появился вопрос. Я хочу написать для андроид загрузчик доп.файлов ну или что-то типа лаунчера (Kotlin + XML верстка), а далее уже запускать саму игру (в одном приложении).
Как это сделать? В самом проекте UE нету папки под андроид (с градлом итд). Есть только в папке самого движка. Может кто знает, что лучше сделать?